# TSQL MD5 generation with UTF8

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

I have a .NET function MD5 that when run on "146.185.59.178acu-cell.com" it returns **f36674ed3dbcb151e1c0dfe4acdbb9f5**

```
public static String MD5(String s)
{
    using (var provider = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Byte b in provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)))
            builder.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I wrote the same code in TSQL, but for some reason only the varchar returns the expected result. The nvarchar returns a different md5 : **f04b83328560f1bd1c08104b83bc30ea**

```
declare @v varchar(150)   = '146.185.59.178acu-cell.com'
declare @nv nvarchar(150) = '146.185.59.178acu-cell.com'


select LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @v), 2))  
--f36674ed3dbcb151e1c0dfe4acdbb9f5
select LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5',@nv), 2)) 
--f04b83328560f1bd1c08104b83bc30ea
```

Not sure what is going on here because I do expect for the nvarchar to return **f36674ed3dbcb151e1c0dfe4acdbb9f5** as it does in .NET

Comment: You should *really* stop using md5; it's not a safe hash. As per [HASHBYTES (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"The MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, and SHA1 algorithms are deprecated starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x). Use SHA2_256 or SHA2_512 instead. Older algorithms will continue working, but they will raise a deprecation event."*

Comment: Also, why would you expect the hashed value of a `varchar` and an `nvarchar` to be the same? They aren't the same datatype.

Comment: But it does, @IanKemp . A `nvarchar` value and a `varchar` value that contains the same characters do *not* have the same value underneath. The only reason something like `'I believe varchar and nvarchar are the same' = N'I believe varchar and nvarchar are the same'` would return true is because the `varchar` is *implicitly* converted to an `nvarchar` first. If you were to compare their underlying (binary) values, they would **not** be the same.

Comment: @Larnu yeah I had a temporary brainfart ;)

Comment: Also note that SQL Server (prior to 2019) has no support for UTF-8, so if you include anything beyond plain old ASCII characters, you're going to see differences even with `VARCHAR` -- the usual default (`Latin1_`) collations are more like Windows-1252. Using `Encoding.Unicode` at least remains consistent with `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: .NET (and Windows, since NT) strings are UTF16LE, not UTF8. The C# code uses the wrong encoding. It should use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You get different hashes because the binary representation of the text is different. The following query demonstrates this:

```sql
declare @v  varchar(150)  = '146.185.59.178acu-cell.com'
declare @nv nvarchar(150) = '146.185.59.178acu-cell.com'

select convert(varbinary(max), @v)  -- 0x3134362E3138352E35392E3137386163752D63656C6C2E636F6D
select convert(varbinary(max), @nv) -- 0x3100340036002E003100380035002E00350039002E003100370038006100630075002D00630065006C006C002E0063006F006D00
```

The extra 0 bytes for the `nvarchar` are due to the fact that it's a 2-byte Unicode datatype. [Refer to MSDN for more information on Unicode in SQL Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Unicode_Defn)

Comment: We know why the SQL strings differ, that's not the question. The question is why .NET Unicode string is not equal to the SQL Unicode string.

Comment: Because UTF-8 encoding is, as its name implies, 8 bits. MSSQL's `nvarchar` is UCS-2, which is 2 bytes or 16 bits. If you want to get the same result in both platforms, use `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` in C# which is close enough to UCS-2 to work for most cases.

Comment: @user11658885 but you never try to calculate the has for .NET strings. Windows and .NET use UTF16LE, always did. Your code uses `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.UTF16`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to explicitly convert **NVarChar** to **UTF8**

Found this code on the net:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnUTF8] (
    @String NVarChar(max)
) RETURNS VarChar(max) AS BEGIN
    DECLARE  @Result    VarChar(max)
        ,@Counter   Int
        ,@Len       Int
    SELECT   @Result    = ''
        ,@Counter   = 1
        ,@Len       = Len(@String)
    WHILE (@@RowCount > 0)
        SELECT   @Result    = @Result
                    + CASE  WHEN Code < 128     THEN ''
                        WHEN Code < 2048    THEN Char(192 + Code / 64)
                                    ELSE Char(224 + Code / 4096)
                        END
                    + CASE  WHEN Code < 128     THEN Char(Code)
                        WHEN Code < 2048    THEN Char(128 + Code % 64)
                                    ELSE Char(128 + Code / 64 % 64)
                        END
            ,@Counter   = @Counter + 1
        FROM    (SELECT UniCode(SubString(@String,@Counter,1)) AS Code) C
        WHERE   @Counter <= @Len
    RETURN  @Result
END
GO
```

And now I use it like this:

```
select LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', [dbo].[fnUTF8](@nv)), 2))
```

Comment: This is a whole lot simpler in SQL Server 2019: `SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'146.185.59.178acu-cell.com') COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)`. Note that a function like this will likely have atrocious performance, which can be an issue if you need to apply it to many rows. In that case performing the hashes client-side and only supplying SQL Server with the bytes is a much better idea (not in the least because SQL Server will insist on raising deprecation events for hashes no longer considered secure).

Comment: Also note that if your input only contains ASCII characters, the simple conversion to `VARCHAR` with (say) a `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation is enough, since both of those encodings are ASCII-compatible. You only need to get tricky with UTF-8 if you have non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! Unfortunately we use SQL 2016 (13.x)

Comment: Why do you insist on using UTF8 instead of UTF16? You wouldn't need to write any of this (slow) code if you used `Encoding.Unicode`. If you have a valid reason for using UTF8, a *fast* alternative would be to write a SQLCLR UDF in C# with the same code as the client.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because there are hundreds of millions of old records that were encoded using .NET on the server which uses UTF8 as described in the OP. So for this to work we need to align ourselves with the existing data...

Comment: @user11658885 you are the Original Poster, and this detail is *FAR* more important than anything else. As I explained, .NET uses UTF16, not UTF8. That's not a matter of opinion or dispute. So does Java. So does JavaScript. You can't safely store UTF8 in a varchar column either, without support for a UTF8 collation (added in 2019), only varbinary. That's because the server translates (or tries to translate) between the stored codepage (specified by the collation)  and the requested encoding, ie UTF16, UTF8, 8-bit codepage etc. UTF8 can *easily* produce bytes that are invalid in some codepage.

Comment: @user11658885 this means, you may have lost data already, perhaps even during insertion. You should be on the lookout for � or the byte sequence 0xFF 0xFD. This is the [Unicode Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), used when a byte sequence results in unrepresentable characters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can honestly say that I have no idea what you are trying to say. For me it is very straightforward, I have a .NET method(see OP) that when given a string, returns this: f36674ed3dbcb151e1c0dfe4acdbb9f5. The problem was to generate the same f36674ed3dbcb151e1c0dfe4acdbb9f5 hash using TSQL. If you know any other way to achieve this on 2016, then post an answer and I will accept.